# Setting HTTP Headers for Rails form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, http-headers

I am currently working on an avatar app powered by Rails where users can upload avatars for their user profile.

I would like to use a custom HTTP header to block public upload requests and only allow requests from my apps. How would I go about doing this with Ruby on Rails?

I am uploading the avatars using AJAX so this may be a bit harder. Also I would prefer not to show the header in the public HTML code otherwise it defeats the object of adding it!

Comment: You want only users on your site to be able to upload? And not allow 3rd party sites to upload?

Comment: That's correct. It will only be for my own apps.

Comment: csrf already helps a little on that.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf

Answer (score 0):

If you add

```
 protect_from_forgery
```

to your application controller, it will block all NON Get requests from 3rd party links. It will add a hidden input value to each form with an authentication token that will be used to check all data that is sent to the servers.

Further reading

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html

[Rails 3.1 - CSRF ignored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270947/rails-3-1-csrf-ignored)

Comment: I'll be using POST requests because the user will be uploading an avatar so I don't think this helps :/

Comment: It will not block POST requests made from users on your own site, it will work fine. It will just block POST requests made from 3rd party sites.

Comment: Hmm ok, but this avatar app will be remote, it will be on a different domain. E.g. my new avatar Rails engine app mapped at app123.com/avatars which sends a post with the users uploaded avatar to myapp.com

Comment: You can always add the csrf token to your ajax request, check the last link I posted. As long as the request has the correct authentication token it will be accepted

Comment: Ah ok, I will take a look into it, thanks. But could a hacker possibly copy that CSRF token and use it, pretending to be my app or not?

Comment: The CSRF is a digital signature and can always be ready by the user/hacker (just check your page source). It is uniquely generated ( calculated from the current session and the server-side secret), you shouldnt have a security issue

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a custom HTTP header (say `X-Foobar-Validity-Status: valid`) and check it in a `before_filter`.

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_header

  def check_header
    unless request.headers['X-Foobar-Validity-Status'] == "valid"
      render json: {"error" => "You are an evil attacker. Go away"}
    end
  end
end
```

However, I would consider this a bad idea.

- Attackers can read the packet dump of your HTTP requests and add the headers, even with jQuery. See the [`jQuery.ajax` headers option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).
- Instead of using a proprietary header, I would use `User-Agent` for this purpose.

Instead, I would sugest using the `protect_from_forgery` mechanism of rails. It makes your life easier and is more secure. Just fetch the authenticy token by a http request in your app and then send it back with your request. This should keep intruders out.

Comment: I can set and check HTTP Headers, that's not the problem. I was just looking to see if it was possible to add a HTTP header (X-My-App) to the form_for tag or can I post it locally, add the HTTP header and then send the request to my avatar server?